# How to group atoms based on boorlen on LIGGGHTS

Tags: group, lammps

I am trying to put atoms that meet a certain boolean condition to a group called "inwardatom". This is the code:

```
variable eatom2 atom "(v_DH>50e-6)&&(v_inOut<0)"
group inwardatom variable eatom2
```

The error message says:

```
ERROR: Illegal group command (group.cpp:341)
```

Can anyone tell me what causes it?